# Initializing a template constructor with a size_t type variable

Tags: class, c++11, templates, size-t, template-classes

I have a class, with a template constructor :

```
class x
{
  public:

    template<std::size_t N>
    x(int matrix[N][N])
     {
        A<N> ob(matrix);
     }
};
```

in main function :

```
int main()
{
   size_t s;
   cin >> s;
   int m[s][s];

   x ob(m); // error
}
```

the error is:

> error: no matching function for call to '`x::x(int [s][s])`'|

I want to create an array whose size is given by the user and pass to `x::x()` which uses it to create a template class object. `A` is defined as:

```
template<size_t N>
class A
{
 ...
};
```

Any solutions to this, I want `N` to be input at runtime and pass it as a template argument. Actually I wanted to pass it directly to `A` but it gives error : `non-const template argument`, so I thought of creating `A` in another class but the error is there too.

I'm using codeblocks 16.01.

Comment: `size_t s; cin >> s; int m[s][s];` isn't C++ standard. The size of an array must be a compile time known value.

Comment: @max66 then how does the compiler allows it

Comment: `template<std::size_t N> x(int matrix[N][N])` is adjusted to `template<std::size_t N> x(int (*matrix)[N])`

Comment: Some compilers accept not standard code if you don't request strict conformance. If you compile with clang++ or g++, try adding `-ansi -pedantic`.

Comment: @max66 do you know any solutions to this how can I pass input `N` at runtime and then use it.

Comment: added an answer; hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will be able to use

```
template<std::size_t N>
x(int matrix[N][N]) { ... }
```

only if `N` is known at compile time.

When you use

```
size_t s;
std::cin >> s;
int m[s][s];

x ob(m); // error
```

that is not true. The value of `s` can be known only at run time. The compiler rightly reports that as an error.

You can remove the compiler error by changing the declaration of the constructor or changing the way the constructor is used. It's not clear from your post what you are trying to do with the argument to the constructor. Hence, I am not able to offer a concrete solution.

> I want `N` to be input at run time and pass it as a template argument.

That is not possible. All template parameters must be known at compile time. You'll have to change your design so you can use a container type whose size can be defined at run time, such as `std::vector`. You can use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to emulate a 2D array.

Comment: I want size of matrix to be input at runtime and then pass this matrix to constructor, how can I achieve this. Actually this N is accepted by another template class which is used within the consstructor

Comment: check the post I've edited it to what I exactly want to do.

Answer (score 0):

> I want N to be input at runtime and pass it as a template argument.

Short answer: it's impossible.

Long answer: as explained by R Sahu, a template parameter must be known at compile time, so it's impossible to use a run time value for it.

In your particular case, if `class x` do not depend from the size `s` but use only it in constructor (?)... if you have limited number of accepted `s` values (from 1 to 5, by example), you can use a `switch` as follows

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
struct foo
 {
   foo (int[N][N])
    { std::cout << "-- foo " << N << std::endl; }
 };

struct bar
 {
   template <std::size_t N>
   bar (int matrix[N][N])
    { foo<N> ob(matrix); }
 };

int main ()
 { 
   std::unique_ptr<bar>  pOb;

   std::size_t s;

   std::cin >> s;

   switch ( s )
    {
      case 1: int m1[1][1]; pOb.reset(new bar{m1}); break;
      case 2: int m2[2][2]; pOb.reset(new bar{m2}); break;
      case 3: int m3[3][3]; pOb.reset(new bar{m3}); break;
      case 4: int m4[4][4]; pOb.reset(new bar{m4}); break;
      case 5: int m5[5][5]; pOb.reset(new bar{m5}); break;
      default: /* throw some exception ? */ break;   
    }

   // do something with pOb
 }
```

This way, inside the single cases, the size of the matrix is known compile time so you pass a compile time value to the template argument.

But, as you can see, you have to write a `case` for every accepted `s` value, so you can think to use a solution like this only is the number of accepted `s` values is very limited.

Obviously, if the content of the `case`'s is big, you can develop a template function for it.

By example, you can develop a `baz()` functions as follows

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::unique_ptr<bar> baz ()
 {
   int m[N][N]; 

   /* do something for m */

   return std::unique_ptr<bar>(new bar{m});
 }
```

so the `switch` become

```
switch ( s )
 {
   case 1: pOb = baz<1>(); break;
   case 2: pOb = baz<2>(); break;
   case 3: pOb = baz<3>(); break;
   case 4: pOb = baz<4>(); break;
   case 5: pOb = baz<5>(); break;
   default: /* throw some exception ? */ break;   
 }
```